# Data in csv file after export

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with data who are exported to a csv file.
It concerns the data with accented characters. Type Data is string.
in my file i have this :

```
TÃ©lÃ©phones et internet;    Abonnement iPad;    13,90Â â‚¬;     DÃ©bit
```

I would like to have :

```
Téléphones et internet;  Abonnement iPad;    13,90€  Débit
```

what code should be used to do this?
Thank you.

EDIT : my code

```
NSMutableString *writeString = [NSMutableString string];

        for (id object in [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects]) {

            NSString * object1 = [[object valueForKey:@"object1Data"] description];
            NSString * object2 = [[object valueForKey:@"object2Data"] description];
            NSString * object3 = [[object valueForKey:@"object3Data"] description];
            NSString * object4 = [[object valueForKey:@"object4Data"] description];;

            [writeString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@; %@; %@; %@\n",    object1, object2, object3, object4]];
        }

NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString* savePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        savePath = [savePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"objectData.csv"];
        [writeString writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  error:NULL];
```

EDIT2 : for viewing i use his :

```
        QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
        previewController.delegate=self;
        previewController.dataSource=self;
        [self presentViewController:previewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [previewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller  previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* savePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    savePath = [savePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"objectData.csv"];

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller
{
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: can you please post your current code?

Comment: Looks like you're not using the correct encoding

Comment: how do you write the string to file? Which encoding?

Comment: sorry i have forgotten a part of code, it's done

Answer (score 1):

Your output looks like it might be correct, the problem seems like it’s in how you are viewing it.

Are you importing it into Excel or something? Excel’s CSV import is very poor in my experience, and it won’t auto-detect incoming UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the encoding that's causing an issue here.

As a side note it's a CSV = Comma Separated Values. You aren't putting the commas in .. ?

Change:

```
[writeString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@; %@; %@; %@\n",    object1, object2, object3, object4]];
```

To:

```
[writeString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@;, %@;, %@;, %@\n",    object1, object2, object3, object4]];
```

This will make the values appear in separate columns when opened in excel, unless you want it all in 1 column ... ?

Comment: Thanks, i want in separate columns.

Comment: Add that in and it should put them in separate ones. :-) Did you fix the encoding issue ? Might be excel not reading it correctly ?